# Blender has stopped working: Crash on startup

Tags: windows, installation

I used Blender version 2.68a last year. I wanted to start using it again, but now whenever I start Blender it simply crashes immediately with the message, "Blender has stopped working". I've tried using multiple different versions, including the most recent 2.71 version w/ 32 bit and 64 bit.

Specs:

OS: Windows 7 64-bit
CPU: i7-4770k @ 3.50 GHz
GPU: GTX 770
RAM: 16.0 GB
Hard Drive: 250 GB w/ 53.1 GB remaining

Comment: Might be the best to report bugs to [https://developer.blender.org/](https://developer.blender.org/). Also try to append the crash log - blender.crash.txt usually written to the systems temporary directory like C:\tmp. You could also try to start blender via console with the -d option and see if it spits some output before crashing.

Answer (score 3):

For these kind of problems you should report a bug in the tracker, as there is really no 'useful answer' possible for this.

If every version of blender has simply 'stopped working' it is likely a problem with your computer (eg. drivers problem).
Otherwise you can try a daily build to see if the problem persists: 
[buildbot](https://builder.blender.org/download/)
If it is a bug, report it: [report a bug](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/create/?project=2&type=Bug)
If you need assistance try any of the listed options: http://www.blender.org/support/